# How can I search a word or phrase in the middle of sentences?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, string

```swift
extension tableviewtest: UISearchBarDelegate {
    func searchBar (_ searchBar:UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        searchArr = copiedArray.filter({$0.prefix(searchText.count) == searchText})
        searching = true
        tableview.reloadData()
    }
}
```

For example, `copiedArray` has some sentences. `["I love you.", "She's beautiful.", "She's a friend of mine."]` when I type "she" into the `searchBar`, I see the two sentences that start with "she". but when I type "beautiful" or "friend". I don't see anything. How should I solve this?

Comment: searchArr = copiedArray.filter({$0.contains(searchText)})

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this for non case sensitive search:

```
copiedArray.filter({$0.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())})
```

for case sensitive search use this:

```
copiedArray.filter({$0.contains(searchText)})
```